# EASELjs drag event, what's wrong here

Tags: javascript, draggable, easeljs

for the start guys thanks for an interesting framework, great job, I'll hope that documentation in the future will be better, in my opinion it lacks real working examples for each object method.

So here is my question, I have a dilemma with with this framework, can some one put a finger on what I did wrong here. I build it from this [example](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/basic.html). Here is the working code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roth/n55jk201/6/) . Last version should move the rectangle on the canvas.

P.S. It's the same without Container.

```
var elementOptions = {
    stroke: 3,
    left: 100,
    top: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 200,
    transformMatrix: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
};

function rectElementCanvasObject(options) {
    var shape,
    rect = new createjs.Graphics()
        .setStrokeStyle(options.stroke)
        .beginStroke('rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)')
        .beginFill('rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)')
        .rect(
    options.left,
    options.top,
    options.width,
    options.height);
    shape = new createjs.Shape(rect);
    if (options.transformMatrix !== undefined) {
        shape.transformMatrix = new createjs.Matrix2D(
        options.transformMatrix[0],
        options.transformMatrix[1],
        options.transformMatrix[2],
        options.transformMatrix[3],
        options.transformMatrix[4],
        options.transformMatrix[5]);
    }
    return shape;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var canvasId, canvasElement, rectangle, dragger;
    canvasId = 'demoCanvas';
    canvasElement = new createjs.Stage(canvasId);
    canvasElement.mouseMoveOutside = true;
    rectangle = rectElementCanvasObject(elementOptions);

    dragger = new createjs.Container();
    dragger.x = dragger.y = 100;
    dragger.addChild(rectangle);

    dragger.on("pressmove", function (evt) {
        evt.target.x = evt.stageX;
        evt.target.y = evt.stageY;
        canvasElement.update();
    });

    dragger.on("pressup", function (evt) {
        console.log("up");
    });

    canvasElement.addChild(dragger);

    canvasElement.update();
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", canvasElement);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick update to your fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/n55jk201/7/

```
dragger.on("pressmove", function (evt) {
    evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
    evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;
    canvasElement.update();
});
```

The rectangle is draggable now (used `evt.currentTarget` instead of `evt.target`), which made it work, and I added a circle at the registration point so you can see how it is positioned when dragging.

Store off the initial x/y offset of the mouse, and apply it to the drag coordinates to make it snap to where your mouse presses, instead of the dragger registration point.

Not sure if this is what you were trying to accomplish or not.

--

Thanks for your feedback on the documentation. We (CreateJS devs + gskinner) are definitely open to adding more examples -- I am not sure how to surface more complex stuff like this though. Definitely open to more specific examples on what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank You! Yes You are right at start I intended to drag elements from where mouse points, but in process I saw that element is not giving live signs on dragging ;) so I decided to post a question here. Also I observed when code line `canvasElement.update();` is removed, element still is draggable, do we really need that line or without it `canvasElement` could trigger some lags on other elements on update? 
-- 
P. S. Sorry I don't have enough reputations to give a +1 but you helped me, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829143/easeljs-glitchy-drag-drop) my answer. I've update the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roth/n55jk201/8/) works very promising :)