# EASELjs pressmove event of container with transformMatrix

Tags: javascript, draggable, easeljs

I have questions please correct me, I dint't find anything about this after some research, You can point me to an answer if one exist. To be specific this is continuation of another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400960/easeljs-drag-event-whats-wrong-here).

After applying a transformation matrix to the container element there is no dragging animation. I figured it out after reading the [documentation](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html#property_transformMatrix):

> transformMatrix Matrix2D
>
> Inherited from DisplayObject: transformMatrix:318
>
> If set, defines the transformation for this display object, overriding all other transformation properties (x, y, rotation, scale, skew).
>
> Default: null

for dragging I used **x** and **y** proprieties of the target object

```
dragger.on("pressmove", function (evt) {
    evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
    evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;
    canvasElement.update();
});
```

so now I think I have to change the matrix values to make dragging animation. Or there is another solution?

---

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roth/n55jk201/10/) with the container with transformation matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. If you apply a `transformMatrix` it overrides the other transformation properties. The most obvious solution, looking at your code is to just not use a matrix, and set the `x` and `y` properties.

https://jsfiddle.net/n55jk201/11/

The other option would be to use `Matrix2D.translate()`, or set `tx`/`ty` on the matrix directly:

https://jsfiddle.net/n55jk201/12/

Obviously there's a lot of code cleanup you could do, but hopefully that conveys the general idea.

Comment: Thank You @gskinner for explanation and the resolve, this is exactly what I wanted. Now I feel more confident with **easeljs**.

  ---

 Also I'll do my best next time on cleaner code ;)